# What is the probability of rolling two 5s or better with 5 dice?

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, conditional-probability, dice

**Preamble**

My question is in the context of a dice game called 31. You have 6 dice and the goal is to have the highest score. If you roll 36, you score 6 points. If you roll 35 you score 5 points and so on up until 30, where you break even. At 29 you lose 1 points and so on.

You roll all the dice at once and after each roll you need to keep at least 1 die on the table. So you roll a maximum of 6 times.

**Question**
If your first roll gives you 6-5-5-x-x-x (where the Xs ≤ 4), what is the probability of getting at least two 5s if you roll five dice (excluding the 6 that you keep). By "at least two 5s" I mean that 5-5-x-x-x is the bottom of the range and 6-6-6-6-6 is the top of the range.

The question could also be worded "On the 2nd roll, do you keep the 5s and roll 3 dice or do you roll them?"

Thanks.

As to add more clarification to the rules of the games, here's a good exemple provided by @Brams28 int the comment

[...]a roll is rolling all the dice you still have left. You have to keep at least one die after each roll, but a single die could potentially be rolled 6 times. Example: I roll 6,5,4,3,2,1 on the first roll. I decide to keep the 6 and the 5 but reroll the 4 others. Now I get 5,2,2,1. I keep the 5 and reroll the other 3. Now I get 6,3,1. I keep the 6 and reroll the last two. I get 5,4. OK, I keep those two (of course!)

Comment: The expected value of a single roll is $3.5$ so trading a sure $5$ for a fresh roll is not a good strategy.  Mathematically speaking, it's even a bad idea to give up a $4$.

Comment: @lulu After the first roll there are 5 more rolls, not just one. So with several more rolls for a die to get a potential 6, maybe it is a good idea to reroll the 5s.

Comment: The EV is different here because if we do roll 5 dice, we hope to get minimally two 5s out of 5 dice,

Comment: @Bram28  So what?  As I understand the rules (possibly incorrectly) you have five separate choices to make.  Clearly you should keep the $6$ and discard anything which came up $≤3$ .  The OP is proposing to toss in the $5's$ which is a bad idea as the expectation is that you will replace each $5$ with a (lower) $3.5$  or have I misunderstood the rules?

Comment: @zaerdy  No, it isn't.  The expected value of your five rolls is the sum of the expectations for each of them separately.

Comment: You should also explore the expected value of keeping one of the 5s and rerolling the other. Since you donl;t get the same number of rerolls for each die, maybe *that* is the best strategy.

Comment: Again, I may be misunderstanding the rules.  But if the goal is maximize your expected score you should keep every roll above a $3$ and re-roll those below.

Comment: @lulu I think we do interpret the rules differently: as i understand, a roll is rolling all the dice you still have left. You have to keep at least one die after each roll, but a single die could potentially be rolled 6 times. Example: I roll 6,5,4,3,2,1 on the first roll. I decide to keep the 6 and the 5 but reroll the 4 others. Now I get 5,2,2,1. I keep the 5 and reroll the other 3. Now I get 6,3,1. I keep the 6 and reroll the last two. I get 5,4. OK, I keep those two (of course!)

Comment: @Bram28  Sorry, where does it say that we can iterate this?  I think you are misreading the OP's statement "You roll all the dice at once and after each roll you need to keep at least 1 die on the table. So you roll a maximum of 6 times."  That claim is just literally true...you have the first roll and then up to five subsequent rolls (one for each of the dice you choose to re-roll).  Nothing suggests you can re-roll several times (though obviously that would change the strategy).

Comment: @zaerdy  Can you confirm or refute my reading of the rules?  I think you are saying you get one chance to re-roll dice and, after the first roll, you can choose to re-roll as many as five of them, but you only get one chance to re-roll.  After you have rolled a die twice you must keep the second value.  Am I reading this correctly?

Comment: @Bram28 This is exactly it. Once you set aside a die, you can't reroll it.

Comment: @zaerdy OK, so given the potential for confusion maybe you should make this more clear in your post. Feel free to use the example I just gave.

Comment: @Bram28 Yes I will add your exemple in the post.

Comment: @zaerdy Ha! I just noticed that with the example I get a total of 31 :)  I assume 31 is a pretty common outcome, hence the name of the game?

Comment: @Brams28 I'm not sure of the probability of getting 31 more than other score, say 32 for exemple. But you begin to score points at 31, which earns you 1 point.

Comment: It looks like the way to tackle this game is to look at it as a [Markov Decision Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process).  It has no cycles, so it's easy to solve bottom up, but it has enough states that I'd want to use a program to compute an optimal strategy.

Comment: @zaerdy It could be an interesting follow-up question: If you play the optimal strategy for this game, then what is the expected total outcome? But I am with Fabio Somenzi: you probably want, if not need, to use a computer to figure out optimal strategy in general, and maybe even for your special case with a 6 and two 5's on the first roll. Indeed, the complexity of this game is such that maybe the optimal strategy is to keep one of the 5's, and reroll the other; that's a possible strategy you want to explore as well.

Comment: @Bram28 Although I would like to see and understand the formula to calculte the probabilty in the 5s scenario, I wouldn't mind using a computer program to calculate the odds. I just don't know such program.

Comment: @zaerdy Yeah, you need some programming skills ... I have some, but I know there are others who are much better than it than I am ... and I don;t quite have the time myself anyway. Hopefully someone will take up the challenge to figure this out. ... and if no one responds on this forum, maybe you can try the puzzling SE

Comment: @Bram28 While I'm eager to learn about almost anything, I have no programming skills whatsoever. Hopefully someone will either find a formulas or help with the programming.

Comment: Given $58.8\%$ chance to roll at least one $6$, vs. $13.2\%$ chance to lose the fives, I'm keeping only the $6$ and rerolling the other five dice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine optimal strategy, I'll start from the end.

With the option of keeping/rerolling one die (i.e. the first five are 'locked in') we keep $\ge4$ and reroll $\le3$ because the expected value $EV_1$ of one $d_6$ is $3.5$

For the option of keeping/rerolling two dice, we need to determine the EV of two $d_6$ with subsequent reroll. To do this, we look at all possible outcomes of two dice and apply the optimal strategy for rerolling one die.
\begin{matrix}
6+6&6+5&6+4&6+\color{red}3&6+\color{red}2&6+\color{red}1\\
5+6&5+5&5+4&5+\color{red}3&5+\color{red}2&5+\color{red}1\\
4+6&4+5&4+4&4+\color{red}3&4+\color{red}2&4+\color{red}1\\
\color{red}3+6&\color{red}3+5&\color{red}3+4&3+\color{red}3&3+\color{red}2&3+\color{red}1\\
\color{red}2+6&\color{red}2+5&\color{red}2+4&\color{red}2+3&2+\color{red}2&2+\color{red}1\\
\color{red}1+6&\color{red}1+5&\color{red}1+4&\color{red}1+3&\color{red}1+2&1+\color{red}1\\
\end{matrix}
The red numbers are those that we reroll. Replace them with $EV_1=3.5$ and sum each outcome.
\begin{matrix}
12&11&10&9.5&9.5&9.5\\
11&10&9&8.5&8.5&8.5\\
10&9&8&7.5&7.5&7.5\\
9.5&8.5&7.5&6.5&6.5&6.5\\
9.5&8.5&7.5&6.5&5.5&5.5\\
9.5&8.5&7.5&6.5&5.5&4.5
\end{matrix}
Add all these together and divide by $36$ and we get $EV_2=\frac{296.5}{36}\approx8.236$

Now, for optimal strategy we note that keeping a $5$ and rerolling the second die $\le3$ gives us an $EV$ of $8.5>EV_2$, so this is good. Also, keeping a $4$ and rerolling the second die $\le3$ gives us an $EV$ of $7.5<EV_2$, so this is not good. Finally, keeping $4\ 4$ gives us $8<EV_2$, so rerolling both dice gives us a slight advantage.

Likewise, we find the optimal strategy for the option of keeping/rerolling three dice by examining all $216$ possible outcomes and apply our optimal strategy for two dice to each. The result is $EV_3\approx13.425$. Now keeping a $5$ and rerolling the other two dice $\le4$ gives us $5+EV_2=13.236$, which is less than $EV_3$ so our optimal strategy is to reroll all three dice unless we have at least two $5$s, then we reroll the third die $\le3$.

Through simulation, I found $EV_4>18.8$, so optimal strategy would be to reroll all four dice unless we already have $5\ 5\ 5\ 5 =20$ or $5\ 5\ 5\ 4=19$

I also found $EV_5>24.4$, so optimal strategy would be to reroll all five dice unless we have five $5$s.

Finally, with optimal strategy throughout, $EV_6>30.1$ for a full round. The creators of this game likely knew this, with a positive score earned only if you exceed this $EV$.

Comment: Your explanation makes a lot of sense. I admit I had to read a couple of times because my lack math background but it's really clearly explained. I understand how you found EV1 and EV2 but how did you come up with EV3 to EV6?

Comment: @zaerdy I found $EV_3$ the same way I found $EV_2$. That is, by writing out the possible combinations of 3 dice, calculating the score for each, and dividing the total by $216$. The others could also be calculated manually, but I just took the values from computer simulation.

Comment: Oh ok I understand. Thanks. Next christmas I'll really play my best 31 game, thanks to you guys XD

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the answer to first question is much help in answering the second, and I agree with [Daniel Mathias's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3065105/632376) to the second—namely that you should roll all 5 dice.   If you do that, and play optimally thereafter, your expected score will be $6 + \frac{8,569,700}{350,699} - 30 \approx 0.44$.

If you keep the 6 and one of the 5s, roll the remaining four dice and play optimally thereafter, your expected score will be $6 + 5 + \frac{989,065}{52,488} - 30 \approx -0.16$.

If you keep the 6 and both 5s, roll the remaining three dice and play optimally thereafter, your expected score will be $6 + 5 + 5 + \frac{13,049}{972} - 30 \approx -0.58$.

If you roll $d$ dice, they show the numbers $m_1 \ge m_2 \ge \dots \ge m_d$, and you decide to keep $k$ of them and roll the remaining $d-k$ (where $1 \le k \le d$), then then the ones you should keep are obviously those showing $m_1, m_2, \dots , m_k$.  If you play optimally thereafter, your expected final sum will be $ES_{d,k} = m_1 + m_2 + \dots + m_k + EV_{d-k}$, where $EV_i$ (to purloin Daniel's notation) represents the maximum expected sum you can obtain by proceeding optimally with $i$ dice.  Your optimal strategy is therefore to choose the value of $k$ for which $ES_{d,k}$ is a maximum.  We therefore get the following recursive equation for the value of $EV_d$:
$$EV_d = \sum_{\mbox{all $d$-tuples of die faces}}
\frac{\max_{1\le k \le d}\left(ES_{d,k}\right)}{6^d} \ \ \ .$$
Using a *[Math Studio](http://mathstud.io/apps/)* script to compute the values of $EV_d$ for $d=3 \mbox{ to } 6$ (the values $d = 1$ and $2$ are trivial to do by hand), I obtained the following:
\begin{eqnarray}
EV_1 &=& \frac{7}{2} \\
EV_2 &=& \frac{593}{72 }\approx 8.236\\
EV_3 &=& \frac{13,049}{972} \approx 13.425\\
EV_4 &=& \frac{989,065}{52,488} \approx 18.844\\
EV_5 &=& \frac{8,569,700}{350,699} \approx 24.436\\
EV_6 &\approx& 30.152\ \ ,
\end{eqnarray}
thus confirming Daniel's analysis.

**Edit:**

It's probably worth giving the following fairly simple explicit description of an optimal strategy.

If you throw the numbers $j_1, j_2, \dots , j_d$ when you throw $d$ dice,

- list those numbers in decreasing order as $m_1, m_2, \dots , m_d$;
- calculate the quantites
  \begin{eqnarray}
  S_0 &=& \sum_{i=2}^d m_i ,\\
   S_k &=& EV_k + \sum_{i=2}^{d-k} m_i  \mbox{ for $k= 1, 2, \dots , d-2$ , and}\\
   S_{d-1} &=& EV_{d-1} ;
  \end{eqnarray}
- determine the value $k^*$ of $k$ for which $S_k$ achieves its maximum value;
- If $k^* = 0$, keep *all* the dice and don't throw any more. Otherwise, keep the $d-k^*$ dice $m_1, \dots , m_{d-k^*}$ and throw the $k^*$ dice $m_{d+1-k^*}, \dots , m_d$ .